# How to add collect feedback webpart to a library by Office Dev PnP?

Tags: workflow, office-dev-pnp

I am creating an office dev pnp template for site provisioning. I created some fields, contenttypes, lists, document libraries, pages etc. I would like to add the OOTB collect feedback workflow to a document library. How can I implement this?

This is the OOTB workflow where I am talking about. I got this picture from the internet.
[image]